# Rao-Cramér inequality

Tags: correlation, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Suppose $p({\bf x},\theta), \theta \in {\bf \Theta} \subset {\bf \mathbb R^k}$ is a (regular) family of distributions.

The score function is defined as $s({\bf x},\theta)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}log(p({\bf x},\theta))=grad(p({\bf x},\theta))$, the Fisher information matrix as ${\bf I}(\theta)=var({\bf s})$ and $E_\theta=({\bf t}({\bf X}))=\theta$.

Deduce the Rao-Cramér inequality from the following expression:
$$corr^2({\bf a}^T{\bf t}, {\bf c}^T{\bf s})=\frac{({\bf a}^T{\bf c})^2}{{\bf a}^Tvar(t){\bf a}\cdot{\bf c}^Tvar(s){\bf c}}$$

where ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf c}$ are fixed ${\bf k}$-dimensional vectors and ${\bf s}$ and ${\bf t}$ are random variables.

The above stated expression comes from the fact that $E({\bf s})={\bf 0}$ and $E({\bf s}{\bf t}^T)={\bf I}$.

I proved this equation, but I don't know how to maximize it over vector ${\bf c}$ and deduce the Rao-Cramér inequality to prove that the correlation coefficient is always less or equal 1.

Comment: Something appears to have gone missing from the end of your first sentence.

Comment: This is potentially an interesting question, but if you still require help, please take the time to include all the information relevant to this problem. You've titled it "Rao-Cramér inequality", yet you've stated no distributional assumptions nor indicated any estimators or parameters, making it impossible to (a) relate it to the information inequality or (b) calculate any Fisher information quantity at all. So, one is left wondering how the title relates to the body of the question. Cheers.